# python timestamp strange value

Tags: python, sqlite, unix-timestamp

In the following script, I fill SQLite databse with several generic values:

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
curs = conn.cursor()

def dynamic_data_entry():

    unix = int(time.time())
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    keyword = 'Python'
    value = random.randrange(0, 10)

    curs.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot (unix, datestamp, keyword, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (unix, date, keyword, value))

    conn.commit()

for i in range(10):
    dynamic_data_entry()
    time.sleep(1)

curs.close
conn.close()
```

One of the field in DB is `unix` that is equal to `int(time.time())`, so it's a current timestamp. However, when I open the DB, I see this:

[image]

This first value of `unix` is several orders less, than it should be. Am I doing something wrong? Or it's just a bug?

Comment: From the date it appears that this is a row inserted earlier. Also note that your table has 11 entries unlike the loop inserting only 10 entries (I assume all rows are visible in screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running this several times?

What are the results of repeat runs?

Is it always the first value that is several orders lower than all other values?

Looking at your table output, it appears that the first result is from 2016, where all following results are from 2017. Is it possible this is related to why the time.time() call returned a much lower than expected number?

Is it possible that you didn't start with an empty DB table?

Comment: yes, after deleting and regenerating the DB, all values are ok... so that original error appears to be some kind of unexplainable magic :)